# Any ideas why my RxJS api call captures every keystroke instead of waiting?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular7, rxjs6

I am trying to do a lookahead with RxJS using Angular 7.3.1 and RxJS 6.4.  When I type, every keystroke is being sent instead of it waiting for a bit of time to capture all keystrokes.

my.service.ts

```
return fromEvent(document.getElementById('input-size-default'), 'input')
            .pipe(
                debounceTime(500),
                map((e: any) => e.target.value),
                filter(earlyText => earlyText.length > 3),
                distinctUntilChanged(),
                switchMap((myText) => ajax.post(this.base_href + ':3000/searchUsers', {user: myText}))
            );
```

component.ts

```
 this.ad.searchCiscoUser()
        .subscribe(response => this.showResults({'results': response}), error => this.showResults({'error': error}));
```

For my search, I typed part of my name and you can see below, 9 calls which should have only happened once.

Results:  [image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As a regular watcher of Angular questions, I think it would benefit from a working example in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular), in addition to the (relevant) code you posted.

Comment: How do you use the Observable returned from `fromEvent`?

Comment: @Mike your rxjs code works for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are subscribing it multiple times. It should be subscribed only once and it will give appropriate result.